# Front page annoyance: is this behavior optimal?

Tags: feature-request, homepage

(Using Firefox 3.5 under XP) When I load the front page of any of the trilogy sites and scroll down past N questions, if I want to see more questions, the option is to load the complete list, which immediately presents me with the same N questions I just scrolled past, possibly with one or two just added at the top of the list.  Would it be a good idea to have the complete list, when loaded from that link, be positioned at the Nth item, so as to minimize overlap?

Answer (score 2):

The behavior differs for me, are you sure you're seeing the same questions?

If I browse to http://stackoverflow.com I get the list of Recent Questions and the `Active` tab is selected. If I click on the "complete list of questions" link at the bottom the page it shows the "All Questions" page with the `Newest` tab selected.

The two lists are quite different. I think a screenshot with obligitary freehand circles would  help us visualise your problem better.

Comment: Wouldn't we need *two* screenshots?